# Callback when list is edited in CoffeeScript/JS

Tags: javascript, callback, coffeescript

I would like to be able to add and delete items from an array in javascript.  When an item is added to the array, I would like another function to be notified about what item was added.  When an item is deleted, I would like a function to be notified what was deleted.

I am using CoffeeScript, but an answer or point in a direction in CoffeeScript or JS would be very helpful.

Comment: Have you written any code to get started? You can build an object that has your array, your adding method, your deleting method, maybe a tracking array to store all actions taken, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
watchMe = []

doPush = (value)->
  # do whatever

watchMe.push = ->
  doPush arguments[0]
  Array.prototype.push.apply @, arguments

# this will call doPush with 'foo', and add 'foo' to the watchMe array
watchMe.push 'foo'
```

You can redefine native `Array.prototype` methods on your array, calling your custom function and then the native javascript parent function.

The example above shows how to override adding elements using `push()`. You would do the same for removing elements using `pop()`, `splice()`, etc.

Check out [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp) for a detailed listing of array methods that you can overload using the method above.

[Here's a link](http://jsfiddle.net/wEWNv/1/) to a more detailed coffeescript demo of the above. You can test locally or copy and paste that over at coffeescript.org

Answer (score 0):

Another cool approach is Array.observe see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/observe). Its part of ECMA 7 Spec, but until then, you can use a polyfill ;-)